# Cannot create Openshift jbossas -7

Tags: jboss, openshift, jboss7.x

Hey guys I am experiencing a weird problem. I was able in past to easily create JBoss Application Server 7 projects following [this](https://blog.openshift.com/a-guide-to-effortless-spring-on-openshift/) simple guide  but now I get an error while creating it. Everything goes fine until this point...

> Activating deployment
>   Deploying JBoss
>   Starting jbossas cartridge
>
> ### jbossas process failed to start
>
> Git Post-Receive Result: failure
>   Activation status: failure
>   Activation failed for the following gears:
>   5730522a7628e18d0b000159 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to
>   execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/5730522a7628e18d0b000159/jbossas

> )
>   Deployment completed with status: failure
>   postreceive failed

Also I have noticed that when I click the link to my Application it throws a 404 error and in the search bar it directs me to blablabla-rhcloud.com/app whereas in the past it was blablabla-rhcloud.com/

I was wondering could this be that they have changed the structure of the Application but not updated the existing starting repository we are supposed to use on github? The controllers have no /app case.

Thanks a lot I hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a rapid create/delete/create cycle (which it sounds like you are), you can encounter lots of different problems, similar to those that you listed.  Try giving it up to 24 hours for the DNS to point to your new application, or try creating your application with a slightly different application name, so that it will update right away.